# How to speed up my sql queries?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a very huge database (MySQL) 7 tables (1000000 record each) I use very simple queries to call information like :

```
select * from matches where match_date='$date'
SELECT * FROM countries WHERE country_id IN (SELECT country_id FROM tournaments WHERE id='$id')
SELECT * FROM tournaments WHERE id='$id'
```

I use indexing for all the columns in the where clause the query is being faster but just a bit.

Does anybody have any helping ideas to improve the speed exponentially?

Comment: Do you get response from the server or there is an error of timeout?

Comment: What do the indexes look like? For example, if your `matches` table has columns `match_id, match_name, match_date` and an index on `match_name, match_date` then technically you have an index on `match_date` but it's not fully optimized.

Comment: show us the tables structures

Comment: Don't write **SELECT * FROM** try to write all names of fields instead.

Comment: also avoid subqueries insetead use joins

Comment: I get response from the server with all the information I want but after long time

Comment: would writing the field names instead of * would make any difference in the response speed.

Comment: 1. How many rows are returned by each of these statements? 2. How much time is "a long time"? 3. What are the hardware specs of your MySQL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worst request seems to be this one:

```
SELECT 
       * 
FROM 
     countries 
WHERE 
      country_id IN (
SELECT
     country_id 
FROM 
     tournaments
WHERE
     id='$id')
```

Try to use this:

```
SELECT 
      countries.*
FROM 
      countries
INNER JOIN
      tournaments
ON
      countries.country_id=tournaments.country_id
AND 
      tournaments.id=$id
```

Index these columns:

1. countries.country_id
2. tournaments.country_id
3. tournaments.id

And better use columns names instead of *.